# работа Pushover с android

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня следующая проблема: я пишу приложение которое будет принимать и посылать уведомления с помощью Pushover, и делаю все по инструкции с официального сайта, однако все равно получаю ошибку:
 https://github.com/sps/pushover4j

вот список всех моих зависимостей:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //Pushover
    implementation 'com.github.sps.pushover.net:pushover-client:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.10'
}
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

но я всё равно получаю ошибку когда отправляю уведомление

```
Process: com.example.testnotifications, PID: 17659
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>
        at net.pushover.client.PushoverRestClient.pushMessage(PushoverRestClient.java:61)
        at com.example.testnotifications.ui.NotificationActivity.sendNotification(NotificationActivity.kt:110)
        at com.example.testnotifications.ui.NotificationActivity.insertNewNotification(NotificationActivity.kt:103)
        at com.example.testnotifications.ui.NotificationActivity.onClick(NotificationActivity.kt:216)
```

Ошибка случается в этом методе:

```
client.pushMessage(
            PushoverMessage.builderWithApiToken("adi4551cxnddnrxtfh63h9i4cf7n1h")
                .setUserId("unq2h3mu8d8joryzs8c9d4migt4y79")
                .setMessage("testing!")
                .build()
        )
```

Зараннее спасибо за любую помощь, сразу оговорюсь, что мне нужно использовать именно pushover, т.к. это тестовое задание